# Как в стиле си записать в бинарный файл матрицу 10x10?

Tags: c, файлы, вывод, файловый-ввод-вывод

Хочу записать в стиле си матрицу 10x10 в бинарный файл, чтобы в нём вместо нормальных чисел была крокозябра наподобии этой: .

Но по какой-то причине вместо крокозябры в нём записывается вот это:

**1 М  М2 М  М21   М3    М12   М1    М7    М4    М7    М17   М
М1    М6    М7    М1    М0    М6    М3    М4    М1    М6    М
М3    М17   М4    М5    М5    М2    М8    М7    М2    М8    М
М5    М7    М7    М5    М6    М6    М1    М6    М0    М4    М
М0    М4    М1    М3    М9    М9    М9    М4    М9    М8    М
М9    М8    М7    М9    М1    М1    М7    М5    М0    М3    М
М9    М6    М7    М9    М4    М4    М0    М0    М7    М0    М
М7    М8    М0    М1    М6    М6    М3    М4    М4    М9    М
М1    М6    М9    М9    М4    М4    М8    М7    М8    М2    М
М3    М9    М9    М9    М8    М8    М9    М0    М3    М0    М
М**

Как сделать так, чтобы во всем файле была крокозябра?

```
 FILE* file;
int matrix[10][10] ={
    { 1 ,2 ,21, 3, 12, 1, 7, 4, 7, 17},
    {1, 6, 7, 1, 0, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6},
    {3, 17, 4, 5, 5 ,2 ,8 ,7 ,2, 8},
    {5, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 6, 0, 4},
    {0, 4, 1, 3, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 8},
    {9, 8, 7 ,9 ,1 ,1 ,7 ,5 ,0 ,3},
    {9, 6, 7, 9, 4, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0},
    {7, 8, 0 ,1 ,6 ,6 ,3, 4, 4, 9},
    {1, 6, 9, 9, 4, 4, 8, 7, 8, 2},
    {3, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 0, 3, 0 } };

char nextLine[3];
sprintf(nextLine, "%c", '\n');

char tab[3];
sprintf(tab, "%c", ' ');


if (fopen_s(&file, "result.bin", "wb") == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < 10;j++)
        {
            char buf[3];
            
            sprintf(buf, "%i", matrix[i][j]);



            fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), file); 
            fwrite(tab, sizeof(char), sizeof(tab), file);
        }
        fwrite(nextLine, sizeof(char), sizeof(nextLine), file); 
            
        
                
    
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    int matrix[10][10] ={
        { 1 ,2 ,21, 3, 12, 1, 7, 4, 7, 17},
        {1, 6, 7, 1, 0, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6},
        {3, 17, 4, 5, 5 ,2 ,8 ,7 ,2, 8},
        {5, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 1, 6, 0, 4},
        {0, 4, 1, 3, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 8},
        {9, 8, 7 ,9 ,1 ,1 ,7 ,5 ,0 ,3},
        {9, 6, 7, 9, 4, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0},
        {7, 8, 0 ,1 ,6 ,6 ,3, 4, 4, 9},
        {1, 6, 9, 9, 4, 4, 8, 7, 8, 2},
        {3, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 0, 3, 0 } };

    if (fopen_s(&file, "result.bin", "wb") == 0)
    {
        fwrite(matrix, sizeof(matrix), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: И как вам хватает терпения отвечать на такие вопросы?

Comment: @avp Воскресенье... :)